# Regex for uppercase and underscores between percentage signs

Tags: python, regex

Regex has never been my strong point. In python I'm attempting to build an expression which matches substrings such as this:

%MATCH%

%MATCH_1%

$THIS_IS_A_MATCH%

It would be extracted by a %MATCH% like this or %LIKE_THIS%

I ended up with this (logically, but does not seem to work): `%[A-Z0-9_]*$%`

So where am I going wrong on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
[%$]\w+[%$]   <-- Notice I put $ because of your sample
```

On the other hand, if you only want uppercase you can use:

```
[%$][A-Z_\d]+[%$]
```

If you only want to match content within %, you could also use:

```
%.+?%
```

Python code

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'[%$]\w+[%$]')
test_str = u"%MATCH%\n\n%MATCH_1%\n\n$THIS_IS_A_MATCH%"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Btw, the problem with your regex is below:

```
%[A-Z0-9_]*$%
           ^--- Remove this dolar sign
```